# python previous element in list loop

Tags: python, algorithm, list

please help with the issue. I need to compare an element of a loop with a previous element in python 3. The code below gives the error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

```
for index, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(a_list, b_list)):
    if j[index] == j[index-1]:
        a = 0
```

Comment: `j` is element which can be int. So it's not subscriptable. You might use list variable in place of `j` (btw, your requirement is not known/clear).

Comment: The following error means that you are getting an `integer value` in `j`. Check what is the value of `j` you are getting, It probably is an integer value.

Comment: I think you meant to do `if a_list[index] == a_list[index-1]:` or something. But that's obviously not going to work for the first element, since `a_list[0 - 1]` is going to look at the last element of `a_list`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get list index and element simultaneously in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072407/how-to-get-list-index-and-element-simultaneously-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

`i` and `j` are elements of `a_list` and `b_list`, and therefore they are not `lists` which you can access with `[]`, but rather, simple `ints` (presumably).

Why not do this?

```
data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 7]

for first, second in zip(data, data[1:]):
    if first == second:
        print('Got a match!')
```

Output:

```
Got a match!
Got a match!
Got a match!
```